# How to correctly set the "filter pipe" so that I enter a value in the component input field, and the other component displays the search results

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

If it is in one component, then everything is fine

```
<input class="top-input" type="text"
       placeholder="Search..."
       [(ngModel)]="term">

<div class="quiz-item" *ngFor="let test of tests | filter: term" (click)="passTestNotify(test)"> ...
```

But I want to enter a value in one component, and in another component the tests should be filtered by name via variable "term" that I entered in the first component.

And I don't know how to do it. My variants: Service, ViewChild, BehaviorSubject, another pipe. Help to solve it please ..

My pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], term): any {
    console.log('term', term);

    return term
      ? items.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(term) !== -1)
      : items;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this through BehaviorSubject. Good thing)